How to load file path explorer and then put chosen file hyperlink in a cell
I found some code as I want to click on the VBA button and it load up the file path explorer and when the file is chosen I want to put it into a particular cell.
Code I currently have is (and I cannot take credit for) is:
Sub CreateHyperLink()
    Dim fd As Object, fPath As String, fName As String, cel As Range
    Set cel = Application.InputBox("Select a cell", "Add Link to File", , , , , , 8)
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\"     'default folder path - MUST  end with[COLOR=#ff0000] [B]\[/B][/COLOR]
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select a file."
        .Filters.Clear
        If .Show = True Then
            fPath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
            fName = Mid(fPath, InStrRev(fPath, "") + 1, 9999)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    cel.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cel, Address:=fPath, TextToDisplay:=fName
End Sub

Problems I have with this are:

It loads up a window that asks which cell I want to put the hyperlink into. The cell I want it to do this into is on a worksheet called "Summary" and in cell G7.

How do I get it to always load a specific folder, when the file path explorer opens it defaults to:
C:\Users\xxxxx - I would like it to default to: C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\invoices.

When it returns the file link in cell G7 I do not want it to return the file path in the cell I want it to show the file name e.g. Invoice123 not C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\invoices\Invoice123.xlsx


I tried the above code but it brought up the box asking where I wanted to input the hyperlink and also shows the hyperlink not the file name.

Set cel = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Summary").Range("G7")

Thanks, appreciate this, it worked great. Last thing is, how do I get it to show the file name and not the hyperlink address?

fName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject").GetBaseName(fPath)

Try these edits:

 Set cel = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Summary").Range("G7")

 .InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\xxxxx\invoices\"

 fName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject").GetBaseName(fPath)


